# Pair Android with Arduino (HC-05) without manually enter pin

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm sending some String data from android to arduino which is HC-05 .

Currently I can send data from android to hc-05 successfully (with or without pairing) and I've used this method to create socket

```
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

            try {
                final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
            }

        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    }
```

as you can see clearly . Its first trying to create `InsecureRfcommSocket`. Its using insecure connection to connect . AFAIK it may caused mitm attack , So I want to use secure communication which is `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord`. but I also don't want user to enter pin at the time of pairing (secure comm socket won't be possible without pin exchange right? : correct me if i'm wrong). so

My Question is :

1. How can I pair hc-05 without user interference in pin input ?(I've tried with intent filter and broadcast receiver but its not working(system always get first priority then my receiver))
2. Is there any way to create secure comm Channel without pairing it ? cause i want only secure Channel and data exchange.
3. If i want to enter pin programatically,Can I use `device.setpin()` or should i have to fire AT-Command for that?

Comment: Check to see if maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19135821/8208808) answer hepls you

Comment: @MihaiBC no brother no luck

Comment: "system always get first priority then my receiver" - I would not be surprised if the Android developers considered it a bug that apps could intercept the pairing dialog and have fixed it since my other question. :-/ What do you set the priority to?

Comment: @Timmmm priory is `filter.priority = IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY`

Comment: Try `SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY-1`. The docs say you can't use `SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY` or higher so it might be being ignored.

Comment: @Timmmm sure . i'll try.